# Finding and processing newly inserted data in postgresql without primary keys

Tags: postgresql, automation, database-trigger

I have a large database table (80+GB) and I need to detect newly entered data, daily, and then process it and determine if it meets quality standards. This table has no primary key or timestamp column, which makes it extremely difficult to determine which data is new vs old. I will likely *not* be able to add new columns to the table, either.

My question here is: how can I determine when new data is inserted, then start a processing job over *only* that data, using Apache-Airflow.The Airflow processing job is already done (coded and runs), it just needs a way to be told to start when new data is inserted and then only run on the new data, not the entire table.

Comment: Have you considered having a two-table solution (with a `UNION ALL` view combining them)? Insert data into one table, then, as part of the quality process, insert it into the other table and delete from the first.

Comment: Let's see: Ensure quality standards on an 80+GB table with no PK not a timestamp. The suggested 2 table approach may be workable. But maybe it's time to review/expand those standards.

Comment: @Belayer I absolutely agree the table needs to have a thoughtful redesign, but that’s not really up to me unfortunately. The two table approach seems to be the only reasonable option right now.

Comment: @Tom: Not necessary a table redesign, although needed, but a review of the standards. If not to retrofit existing but at least for future. But I guess that could be an even bigger project so it's not likely either. But I found that if no one at least suggests what needed it'll never get done.